# How to assign xacro arguments to xacro macro parameters?

Tags: ros, urdf, ros-melodic, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am initialising a macro in my xacro file as
`<xacro:macro name="sensor_d435" params="name:=realsense_d435_camera topics_ns:=realsense_d435 parent *origin">`.

I have a xacro argument with the name `robot_namespace` in my launch file. I want to assign it to the `topics_ns` while initializing my macro, something like: `topics_ns:=$(arg robot_namespace)`. When I do this and launch my original launch file, I get an error saying `invalid expression: $(arg`

Probably, it is seeing `$(arg` and `robot_namespace)` as 2 different and separate parameters.
Any way how I can achieve what I want?

TIA

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382691/how-to-assign-xacro-arguments-to-xacro-macro-parameters?/) by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2021-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I raised an issue regarding this on `xacro`'s GitHub and a kind developer created a [PR](https://github.com/ros/xacro/pull/278) for this feature request. It has now been merged. I hope now it will be possible to assign argument names to macro parameters.
Thank you, community!

---

Originally posted by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) with karma: 277 on 2021-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0